# Pandas pivot table + keep 2 additional columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I'm trying to pivot this df:

```
data = {
    'account': ['Account 1', 'Account 1', 'Account 1', 'Account 1', 'Account 1', 'Account 2'],
    'product': ['Product 1', 'Product 1', 'Product 1', 'Product 2', 'Product 3', 'Product 1'],
    'metric': ['Meric 1', 'Meric 1', 'Meric 2', 'Meric 1', 'Meric 1', 'Meric 1'],
    'date': ['Date 1', 'Date 2', 'Date 3', 'Date 4', 'Date 5', 'Date 1'],
    'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
}

pd.DataFrame(data)

     account    product   metric    date  value
0  Account 1  Product 1  Meric 1  Date 1      1
1  Account 1  Product 1  Meric 1  Date 2      2
2  Account 1  Product 1  Meric 2  Date 3      3
3  Account 1  Product 2  Meric 1  Date 4      4
4  Account 1  Product 3  Meric 1  Date 5      5
5  Account 2  Product 1  Meric 1  Date 1      6
```

Into view like this BUT with **date & product columns added as is**

```
new.pivot_table(index='account', columns='metric', values='value')
```

**What I have so far**:

```
metric     Meric 1  Meric 2
account                    
Account 1      3.0      3.0
Account 2      6.0      NaN
```

**What I'm looking for**:

```
metric     Meric 1  Meric 2 product  date
account                    
Account 1      1.0      Nan Product 1 Date 1
Account 1      2.0      Nan Product 1 Date 2
Account 1      Nan      3   Product 1 Date 3
...
```

The only thing is that account will be repeated, but this is exactly what I want - if we have same product for different dates.

Comment: Can you replace `xxx` by actual values?

Comment: @jezrael updated expected view with actual values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add both columns to parameter `index` in `pivot_table`, then convert second and third levels to columns and change ordering of columns:

```
df = (new.pivot_table(index=['account','product','date'], columns='metric', values='value')
         .reset_index(level=[1,2]))
df = df[df.columns[2:].tolist() + df.columns[:2].tolist()]

print (df)
metric     Meric 1  Meric 2    product    date
account                                       
Account 1      1.0      NaN  Product 1  Date 1
Account 1      2.0      NaN  Product 1  Date 2
Account 1      NaN      3.0  Product 1  Date 3
Account 1      4.0      NaN  Product 2  Date 4
Account 1      5.0      NaN  Product 3  Date 5
Account 2      6.0      NaN  Product 1  Date 1
```

Comment: thank you so much! don't know how I missed adding these keys to the index..